# Qt 5.x Custom Widget Creation and Use

Tags: qt

I'm returning to Qt programming after an absence of a couple of years, and I'm starting with Qt 5.1. In the past, I've used the designer, and a good deal of hand-crafted code to put Qt projects together. Now, we'd like to make heavy use of the Creator.

But I'm not seeing how to accomplish some seemingly basic tasks. For example, I'd like to design a custom widget, then pull it into my main application, but although the Creator allows me to make multiple files within a project, they seem to have no knowledge of one another as far as the Creator itself is concerned. Once my widget is built, there's no way to pull it into the main application, and also no way to test it independently, at least that I'm able to find.

It seems as though documentation for Qt has taken a major blow somewhere along the line. It is cursory and thin, compared to the extremely detailed docs that used to be available in the past.

If someone can point me to a decent collection of documentation and tutorials, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 5):

**Unit Testing**

Use the Qt Test module: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttest-index.html

**Using Custom Widgets**

I'm not 100% sure what you meant by *"pull [the widget] into the main application"*.

If you want to combine your custom widgets in Qt Designer, add a placeholder (blank) QWidget in the parent and Promote it to your custom widget:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets

If you want to combine your custom widgets in C++, instantiate your custom child widget and add it into the parent widget's layout using `QLayout::addWidget()`:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addWidget

If you want to make your application display a custom widget, simply `#include` the widget's header, instantiate the widget, and call `QWidget::show()`:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#show

If you want to develop your custom widget in a separate standalone project, include it in your main project as a Subproject:

- https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-creating.html#adding-subprojects-to-projects
- [How do I make a subproject with Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405/how-do-i-make-a-subproject-with-qt)

**Other Notes**

- Qt Designer has been integrated into Qt Creator for many years. Qt Designer and its documentation have changed very little between Qt 4.8 and Qt 5.
- The extremely detailed docs for Qt 5 are at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/. There are links to useful doc collections in the nav bar on the right.
- I recommend exploring QML/Qt Quick. It's much easier to create QML-based GUIs compared to widget-based GUIs. It's still a young technology though, so it might not suit your needs yet: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlapplications.html

Comment: Perhaps I'm not being clear. What I'd like to do is build a custom widget, then make use of it in another (possibly several other) projects. It isn't clear to me how to accomplish this in Creator. In the past, I did it more or less manually, creating the widget in a subdirectory of a larger project, then either promoting a similar widget as you describe, or taking the additional step of creating a Desigener plugin for it. Does Creator not allow multi-part projects? Qt Quick is new to me, but may be useful. Still learning it, although it has several limitations I don't care for, or seems to.

Comment: I see. I've added links to Subprojects in the answer. HTH.